# Can't use variable in function

Tags: python

I want to make a guessing game where if someone guesses the right number they get coins. When I create a function called guess_home (to act as a home screen) I cannot access variables in the main file. I am using two files, one for the main code, and one for all the functions to save space. when I made a variable in my main code, I cannot access it in my functions code. I was wondering if there was a way to allow me to use a variable in both files?

Main Code:

```
from guessing_functions import guess_game, guess_home

coins = 0

q1 = input("Wanna play a game? ")
if q1 == "ya":
    guess_game()
    coins += 5

guess_home()
```

Functions:

```
def guess_home():
    main_q = input("Type 'coins' to see you coin balance, or 'again' to play again")
    if main_q == "coins":
        print ("Your coins balance is: " + coins)
    if main_q == "again":
        guess_game()
```

Comment: What are those bendy line thingies between "guess_home" and ":" for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variable as a parameter. If you pass an int you need to typecast before you print it:

```
def guess_home(coins):
    main_q = input("Type 'coins' to see you coin balance, or 'again' to play again")
    if main_q == "coins":
        print ("Your coins balance is: " + str(coins))
    if main_q == "again":
        guess_game()
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid global variables. When a function needs a value, pass it as an argument.

```
# Definition
def guess_home(coins):
```

and

```
# Call site
guess_home(coins)
```

Comment: when I do that, it tells me that coins must be a string, not an int.

Comment: That's a different problem.